# Currency Codes in Twitter Bootstrap Icons or ASCII Codes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, icons, ascii, symbols

I am building a eCommerce website in twitter bootstrap, in it i want to use **currency symbols/icons** in it. I have to alternatives, write the currency codes in **ascii codes** and second is by twitter bootstrap icons where i create my own css to a specific icon and embed the image of it...

For the reason i want all the currency codes of all countries specifically **indian rupees** , what way i use for this, i think indian rupees is not in ascii codes, so i want to use icons for it but i also didnt able to find the icons or group of icons where all icons in one place, could anyone suggest me what to do?

BY using twitter bootstrap icon, i have to just add:-

```
<i class="icon-rupee"></i>
<i class="icon-dollar"></i>
<i class="icon-yen"></i>
<i class="icon-euro"></i>
and so on...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this i have just used some tools and assets to make a good and simple solution for this...

Icons i have taken from [Free Icon Set](http://www.gentleface.com/free_icon_set.html) for currencies and used [Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/index.html) for some add-on features and icons to [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)...

For a **Dollar sign**, i have written this css:-

```
.icon-dollar {
    background-image: url("../images/cur_dollar_icon&16.png");
}
```

And for all **custom currency icons**. i have written:-

```
.icon-bp, .icon-dollar, .icon-euro, .icon-yen, .icon-rupee {
    background-position: center center;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

**Html as:-**

```
<i class="icon-dollar"></i>
```

So you can add easy and many icons as you can, thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a *free* currency sign Webfont but you can use `&#8377;` ₹ or `&#8360;` ₨ in HTML to display the indian ruppee sign, which should work on most modern operating systems.

You can find other currency symbols f.ex. [in this PDF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf) and decode them in HTML.

**Edit:**
The new version 3.2.0 of [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/#new) supports now the [rupee symbol](http://fontawesome.io/icon/inr/).

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am not sure that writing ascii codes could be a perfect solution, can we use icons instead, where from i get all the currency icons?

Comment: Why the down vote? I would prefer using the currency codes in Unicode instead of icons because it's more accessible. Does it have any disadvantages for you?

Comment: the main reason behind my downvote is browser support, may be all of ascii currency codes didnt work in all browsers... i am particularly talking about IE...

Comment: Ascii defines just 128 characters, Unicode offers much more characters. HTML entities like `&8377;` are supported by *all* browsers, but you are right that old systems may not have a font where these characters are defined (more info on this in section "Unicode" of this [Ruppee sign Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign)). Maybe you will find a [Google Webfont](http://www.google.com/fonts/) that support all your currency signs encoded in HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

Rupees are supported by standard UTF8, and all of the default font families (Ariel, Currier, Times New Roman, San Serif, etc.)  Just make sure your header is UTF compliant and use "\u20b9" which should escape to your symbol.