# Angular: Is there any way to add rupee prefix to bootstrap input field?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Here's my `html` file. I want to add  `₹` prefix to my input field. I'm working on an angular project and using botstrap for html pages.
**product.component.html**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price">Price</label>   <==Want to add here
            <input id="price" type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select id="category"class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imageUrl">Image Url</label>
            <input id="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hope this will help solve you the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899472/currency-codes-in-twitter-bootstrap-icons-or-ascii-codes

Comment: you want this symbol to appear after the user enters a number or be there at all times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this.

[image]

Use input-group class to prepend and append text/icon.

Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">₹</div>
        </div> 
        <input id="price" type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference

[Bootstrap 4 Input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group)